# Can't set JAVA Path in batch

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, windows-10-desktop

i have a problem with set a temporary variable in batch for java under Windows10. Java_home is working, but variables for java.exe are everytime empty.....
with:

```
@echo on
set JAVA_HOME = C:\openjdk\java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-1.windows.ojdkbuild.x86_64
set JAVA_HALLO = %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
set JAVA = %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
%JAVA_HALLO% -version
%JAVA% -version
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version
echo %JAVA%
echo %JAVA_HALLO%
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

i got

```
D:\>test.bat

D:\>set JAVA_HOME = C:\openjdk\java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-1.windows.ojdkbuild.x86_64

D:\>set JAVA_HALLO = C:\openjdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1.b08.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin\java

D:\>set JAVA = C:\openjdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1.b08.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin\java

D:\>-version
Der Befehl "-version" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

D:\>-version
Der Befehl "-version" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

D:\>C:\openjdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1.b08.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin\java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

D:\>echo
ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON).

D:\>echo
ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON).

D:\>echo C:\openjdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1.b08.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64
C:\openjdk\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1.b08.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64
```

Can somebody tell me the problem, please ?

Comment: Use the syntax `set "VAR=Value"`; yours (`set VAR = Value`) assigns a variable called `VAR` + _space_…

Comment: Try to remove the space before and after the = when you set the variables.

Answer (score 0):

i found the error.....the empty space by the equals

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\openjdk\java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-1.windows.ojdkbuild.x86_64
set JAVA_HALLO=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
set JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
```

Comment: Actually, you should use doublequotes to protect possible hidden unwanted trailing spaces too, e.g. `Set "JAVA_HOME=C:\openjdk\java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-1.windows.ojdkbuild.x86_64"`. In addition to that you should include the extension for your java executable too, i.e. `Set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"`, then for extra safety, you should also surround that variable, when used, with doublequotes, to protect it from possible poison/space characters too, e.g. `"%JAVA%" -version`.